# How to revert SharedPreferences changes?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences in my app. I have a new requirement that the user can change these settings, but when they are leaving the Preference Screen they must be prompted to confirm the settings changes.

If they choose not to, what is the best way to revert the changes to whatever the state of the preferences when the user first opened the Preference Screen?

**edit**

as per @Sachin Gadagi's suggestion, I'm thinking of the following, but I wonder is this the correct way:

```
var editor = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this).Edit();
foreach (var sp in _prefsBackup)
{
    // I know they're all bool
    editor.PutBoolean(sp.Key, (bool) _prefsBackup[sp.Key]);
}
editor.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it.

```
                var editor = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this).Edit();
                foreach (var sp in _prefsBackup)
                {
                    editor.PutBoolean(sp.Key, (bool)_prefsBackup[sp.Key]);
                }

                editor.Commit();
                base.OnBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion , store the preferences in variables ,and use ***onBackPressed()*** function .
On BackPressed event, ask to keep the change or not . and set variables accordingly .

Comment: I'm thinking along that line. Just wondering if it's the best way to go!